# How to prevent Windows Explorer from rearranging pinned Quick Access items

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-quick-access

I have a lot of items pinned in Windows Explorer's Quick Access. However, I find it irritating when windows rearranges these items seemingly at random. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Note that I already know how to prevent windows from adding items to Quick Access; that is not the issue. This issue is the random rearranging of the items I have already pinned.

Comment: Look at this article to see if QA is working as it should. It does change the order over time.  Also, it is really misbehaving, you may need to clear QA and start it again: https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/4031/windows-10-tip-clean-up-quick-access

Comment: It's doing everything I want except for the fact that the pinned items are changing order. All I'm asking is if there's a way that off.

Comment: I saw that in the article I posted.

Comment: No, it doesn't. That article tells you how to prevent windows from adding recently and frequently used file to QA. That's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Quote from the Article above "Finally, Quick Access changes over time. As you access files and folder locations on your PC and local network, these locations will appear in Quick Access. If you view Quick Access in File Explorer, you will see sections for both Frequent folders and Recent files, which is exactly what it sounds like.

Odder still, the Quick Access section in the Navigation pane will start to change over time to: Windows will automatically pin folders that you regularly access to the list."

Comment: I don't have a "Recent Folders" and "Recent Files" section on my quick access because I unchecked both of those options a long time ago. I'm not sure you realize Windows still rearranges the pinned QA files even after you've unchecked "Show recently used files in QA" and "Show frequently used folders" in QA?

Comment: I am not certain, but I think the behavior you describe is part of Windows 10 Q&A.